# Why LinearModelFit is slower than NonlinearModelFit?

Tags: fitting, performance-tuning

Why [`LinearModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LinearModelFit.html) is slower than [`NonlinearModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html)?

```
data = Table[{x, 0.68 x - 0.33 + RandomReal[1000]}, {x, 0, 200000}];

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, a + b x, {a, b}, x] // AbsoluteTiming
> {0.081027, FittedModel[500.052 +0.679998 x]}

lm = LinearModelFit[data, {1, x}, x] // AbsoluteTiming
> {1.168421, FittedModel[500.052 +0.679998 x]}
```

It's almost 16 times slower, than [`NonlinearModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the actual fitting is quite fast:

```
Fit[data, {1, x}, x] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.0480027, 498.465 + 0.680009 x}

I must assume that the extra time is spent on the construction of the `FittedModel` object.

The `InputForm` of the `FittedModel` objects give some clue.  The `lm` model is considerably more complicated, having two sections additional to the input data that are not in the `nlm` model.  Using highly abridged data:

```
xlist = Sort @ RandomInteger[1000, 10]
data = Table[{x, 0.68 x - 0.33 + RandomReal[1000]}, {x, xlist}];
```

> ```
> {51, 149, 191, 248, 285, 336, 415, 478, 676, 833}
> ```

```
Last @ nlm // InputForm
```

> FittedModel[{"Nonlinear", {a -> 417.39173824442327, b ->
>   0.8789467743580213}, {{x}, a + b*x}}, {1}, {{51, 427.5070649996163}, {149, 866.0983410584965}, {191, 733.5246301659654}, {248,
>   226.92795545444534}, {285, 994.7118043721894}, {336, 315.78528074990083}, {415, 1001.5398600985629}, {478, 603.1246737474789}, {676, 777.5181444646195}, {833, 1445.8827150320312}}, Function[Null, Internal`LocalizedBlock[{a, b, x}, #1], {HoldAll}]]

```
Last @ lm // InputForm
```

> ```
> FittedModel[{"Linear", {417.39173824442327, 0.8789467743580213}, {{x}, {1, x}}, {0, 0}}, {{1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.}}, 
> {{51, 427.5070649996163}, {149, 866.0983410584965}, {191, 733.5246301659654}, {248, 226.92795545444534}, {285, 994.7118043721894}, {336, 315.78528074990083}, {415, 1001.5398600985629}, {478, 603.1246737474789}, 
> {676, 777.5181444646195}, {833, 1445.8827150320312}}, {{1., 51.}, {1., 149.}, {1., 191.}, {1., 248.}, {1., 285.}, {1., 336.}, {1., 415.}, {1., 478.}, {1., 676.}, {1., 833.}}, Function[Null, Internal`LocalizedBlock[{x}, #1], {HoldAll}]]
> ```

Of course the extra sections are very simple: a vector of ones and a list of the `xlist` values paired with ones, which doesn't explain why this is slower, but I suspect it may point in the direction of an explanation.  That's all I've got.